# Can 〜てもいい indicate you are giving yourself permission?

Tags: grammar

I saw this picture online and it was of someone giving their business card to a girl (presumably to become an idol). The girl says in the picture:

> う〜んどうしよかなぁ
>   今キスしてくれたらアイドルになってもいいよ

Attempt at translation:

> Hmm, I wonder what I should do? If you kiss me right now, it's okay for me to become an idol.

When I was first learning it seemed that when it was 「〜てもいい(です)か？」it was asking for permission for yourself and when it was just 「〜てもいい」it was for giving permission to someone else. It seems like the girl in the statement above is giving permission to herself or is my interpretation of the sentence wrong?

Comment: Just for context, the sentence is probably by 速水奏【はやみかなで】 from the game アイドルマスター シンデレラガールズ. [dic-nicovideo](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E9%80%9F%E6%B0%B4%E5%A5%8F), [18.atikwiki](http://www18.atwiki.jp/imas_cg/pages/467.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Giving yourself permission**" may be one way to interpret it.  You are certainly on the right track with that.

In my own words, however, it would be more like "**agreeing (or consenting) to do something**" in this particular context.

Comment: Big thanks! It's that tiny difference in nuance which stopped me from getting my head around what that meant until your explanation cleared it up for me.